# How to check if bottom sheet fills full screen in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet with a list of items.
I want rounded corners at the top if it is not entirely open. (Less content)
If there is more content, the bottom sheet will be filling the screen and the list will be scrollable.

**In this case, I want to change the bottom sheet shape without the rounded corners.**

The content is dynamic.

A simplified example of the use-case.

**Code**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun openModalBottomSheetState(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        modalBottomSheetState.show()
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun BottomSheetFillCheck() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
        skipHalfExpanded = true,
    )
    var bottomSheetType by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            value = BottomSheetType.NONE,
        )
    }
    var count by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val colors = listOf(
        Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.DarkGray, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Cyan, Color.Gray,
        Color.Magenta, Color.LightGray, Color.Yellow, Color.Red, Color.Green,
    )

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(
            topStart = 16.dp,
            topEnd = 16.dp,
        ),
        sheetContent = {
            LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                items((0 until count).toList()) {
                    Row(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(100.dp)
                            .background(colors[it]),
                    ) {}
                }
            }
        },
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    count = 2
                    openModalBottomSheetState(
                        coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                        modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                    )
                },
            ) {
                Text("Open Sheet with 2 items")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    count = 6
                    openModalBottomSheetState(
                        coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                        modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                    )
                },
            ) {
                Text("Open Sheet with 6 items")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    count = 12
                    openModalBottomSheetState(
                        coroutineScope = coroutineScope,
                        modalBottomSheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                    )
                },
            ) {
                Text("Open Sheet with 12 items")
            }
        }
    }
}
```